# Select a Unknown Tag that stands after a Known Tag in jSoup

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

[image]

I have to select the `<ul>` indicated at the picture using jSoup.
The list always appear after a header (`<h2>`) that contain a `span` having id `Events`.

Comment: I can select the span using : `Elements test = doc.select("span#Events");` and the parent header by: `Element divGuarantee = test.get(0).parent(); ` But can't select the list.

Comment: `Node node = divGuarantee.nextElementSibling();` works for me

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<ul>`-tag you want, you can do it by first selecting the known tag and then check for it's parent and it's sibling. This can be achieved with the following code:

First, select the known tag `Events`

```
    Elements span = doc.select("span#Events");
```

To get the `<h2>`-tag we use the following

```
    Elements parent = span.parents();
```

From this, we can select the next sibling of the `<h2>`-tag which is the `<ul>`-tag you want

```
    Node ul = parent.first().nextSibling();
```

Print it out to see if it works for you

```
    System.out.println(ul.toString());
```

This should print out

```
<ul>
 ...
</ul>
```